# Relation between medians of random variables X and Y related to each other

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, inverse-function, median, cumulative-distribution-functions

> Given $X$ be a random variable and let $f$ be an increasing function and $Y$ be another random variable with $Y=f(X)$. What is the relation between medians of $X$ and $Y$?

I tried the above by finding the CDF of distribution defined by $Y$ as below:

$F_{Y}(y)=P(Y \leq y)$ where $y$ is the median

$F_{Y}(y)=P(f(X) \leq y)$

$F_{Y}(y)=P(X \leq f^{-1}(y))$ as function $f$ is strictly increasing

$F_{Y}(y)=F_{X}(f^{-1}(y))$

Thus, if $y$ is the median for distribution defined by $Y$, then $f^{-1}(y)$ is the median for distribution defined by $X$ or it can be represented as $y=f(x)$ where $y$ and $x$ are medians of the distribution defined by $Y$ and $X$.

Can you please let me know if my approach to the above formulation is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your reasoning is correct. In general, if we call  $q_{\alpha}^Z$ the $\alpha$ quantile of a generic r.v. $Z$, this respects:

$\alpha=F_Z(q_{\alpha}^Z)$

Now let's consider $Y=f(X)$. Using your last equation for $y=q_{\alpha}^Y$:

$\alpha=F_Y(q_{\alpha}^Y)=F_X(f^{-1}(q_{\alpha}^Y))=F_X(q_{\alpha}^X)$

therefore:

$q_{\alpha}^X=f^{-1}(q_{\alpha}^Y)$

and:

$q_{\alpha}^Y=f(q_{\alpha}^X)$

For $\alpha=1/2$ you get your mapping between medians.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation